# Teaching integration (online). Logical progression in subject?

Tags: calculus, tutoring

I've lectured integration from the very basics, having covered the following;

- What are integrals, and what do they represent?
- Indefinite integrals as the opposite of derivatives.
- Using the power rule for derivatives to provide the power rule for integration.
- Integral as infinite sum.
- Area under curve, and area between two curves.
- Volume of solid of revolution.
- Integration by substitution.
- Integration by parts.
- Integration by partial fraction expansion.
- Improper integrals

All this is a total of 41 short (5-10 min) lectures (videos), accompanied by example problems etc.

I'm wondering what I should do next, such that it will be natural step forward. Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard Calculus sequence. Why not look at what's on the AB/BC AP tests? To re-phrase: Why would your progression differ from the standard ones in high school or college intro to Calc classes? If it wouldn't, this should be trivial (e.g., imitate James' text); if it would differ, then perhaps you can explain *how* in the body of your question.

Comment: I'm not decided on whether or not it would differ. So far, I've come up with the plan by myself.

I tried looking at the syllabus for AP Calc, but it was very vague, and didn't really cover the sub-sections.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Differential equations are intentionally left out. I cover that in a separate chapter. Numerical methods are definitely something I should cover though.

As for scope, I guess as far as I can go in terms of single-variable. I've also been tipped that I should go into multivariable calculus as well, but I expect I'll be doing that in a separate course, because it will cover both differentiation and integration.

Comment: trigonometric substitution and/or hyperbolic substitution. The idea of implicit verses explicit substitution.

Comment: Application in sciences, e.g. physics.

Comment: Approximating sums by integrals.

Comment: I suggest converting some or all of the above comments into one or more answers, as this is currently an unanswered question.

Comment: @JW - Yeah, the comments have indeed been helpful, and I think I'll be able to compile a decent syllabys of sorts from it. That said, I'd always welcome more input and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I would **move integral as infinite sum** to the second topic, with crude numerical calculations, or by drawing a curve on graph paper and counting how many squares are covered.

I would **add**:

- techniques for numerical integration**, e.g. trapezoidal rule and Simpson's rule.
- integrating by computer, for both symbolic and numerical results.
- applications in physics:  distance from velocity, impulse from force, moments.
- applications in biology or economics, e.g. population growth as the integral of population changes, or GDP growth as the integral of changes in GDP.
- applications in statistics, e.g. normal probabilities as the area under the normal distribution.

I would **remove**

- integration by partial fractions, which I find unimportant and distracting for a course at the level of "What are integrals?"
- integration by parts, for the same reason
- volumes of revolution, if pressed for time, because it fits better in the multivariable class
- improper intergals, if pressed for time, because students are unlikely to appreciate the subtleties

That keeps the total lectures at roughly the same length, with a different emphasis.

Comment: I would keep integration by parts, only because of how important it is for later math.  A large part of my work as an analyst seems to be integration by parts...

Answer (score 2):

As Michael E2 mentions, a next step could be numerical integration, introducing methods such as the rectangle rule, trapezoidal (trapezium) rule and Simpson's rule.

(I have made this answer Community Wiki.)